# I wish to create a table, but it always gets out of the page, I tried using the tabularx package but it ends up giving some errors

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llllll}

Ester & Temperature \degree C & Initial reaction rate/ mmol min g & Melting point of Product \degree C & Conversion of Alcohol (\%) & Conversion of Acid (\%)\\
Cetyl Palmitate & 65-67 & 3.4 & 50-51 & 98 & 99\\
Behenyl Behenate & 85-88 & 2.9 & 69-73 & 99 & 98\\
Dibehenyl adipate & 90-93 & 1.4 & 70-73 & 99 & 99\\
Dibehenyl Sebacate & 88-90 &1.4 &71-74 & 95 & 99   
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to wide column headers. you should find the way to make them shorter. one attempt can be (with use `\small` font size, `tabularx`, `multirow`, `makecell` and `booktabs` packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l CC CC C @{}}
    \toprule
\multirow[t]{3}{*}{Ester}
    & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\centering    Temp. \degree C}
            & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\centering    Initial rate (mmol)}
                    & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\centering    Melting point \degree C}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Conversion of}     \\
    \cmidrule{5-6}
    &       &       &       & \makecell[t]{Alcohol\\ (\%)}
                                    & \makecell[t]{Acid\\ (\%)}     \\
    \midrule
Cetyl Palmitate     & 65 -- 67 & 3.4   & 50 -- 51 & 98    & 99      \\
Behenyl Behenate    & 85 -- 88 & 2.9   & 69 -- 73 & 99    & 98      \\
Dibehenyl adipate   & 90 -- 93 & 1.4   & 70 -- 73 & 99    & 99      \\
Dibehenyl Sebacate  & 88 -- 90 & 1.4   & 71 -- 74 & 95    & 99      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
 with some experience with `latex` above code is "self descriptive" ... but, you just learn it, it looks "cryptic" ...

- package `gensymb` is used for some symbols as `\degree` (i'm not familiar with it, for such purposes i rather use `siunitx`)
- package `booktabs` provide horizontal table rules (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, ...), which gives to table professional looks
- package `makecell` helps to create common layout for tabular material. from it is macro `\makecell` which enables to set multi line text in tables' cells. by it i force cells' content to be in two lines (for better looking)
- package `multirow` vertical merge table cells
- package `tabularx` provide column type `X` which width package itself calculate. in its cells a text is automatically broken into more lines (if it is longer than cells widths) and justified, but enables to define new columns type with command `\newcolumntype{<name>}{<properties>}`. for example with `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` you define that cells of `C` center text in it.

for more details i encourage you read packages documentations which is part of your `latex` installation. if you have MikTeX, then you file them in sub directory `doc`, or search it on the web.

Comment: +1. Do please change `-` to `--` (to create en-dashes) in columns 2 and 4.

Comment: i love this forum, i started latex a week ago, and thanks to you all, i've had all my problems solved

Comment: @Zarko, could you please help me understand as to what is this code used for, and also it's syntax, sorry for the inconvenience,    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

Comment: @RBK, see added explanation in answer. if answer solve your problem, than please accept it (with clicking check mark at top left side of answer). happy tex-ing!